# postgres plugin not loaded in zabbix-agent2

Tags: postgresql, zabbix

I am using zabbix since a couple of years. Now I want to start monitoring postgresql.

I configured everything with zabbbix-agent2 but don't see any values. The are errors indicating unknown metrics regarding postgresql.

I had look and realized, that the postgres plugin is installed, the config files is in the plugin directory but the agent is not loading the plugin, although all other plugins are loaded successfully.

Any ideas why only the postgresql plugin is not loaded?

UPDATE:

I found out, the ansible role which I use set the include only to
/etc/zabbix/zabbix-agent2.d/

The plugin configs are lying now in the usb dir plugins.d

seems there is no Include config which includes configs in
/etc/zabbix/zabbix-agent2.d/

and

/etc/zabbix/zabbix-agent2.d/plugins.d

in one Include parameter.

Something like

/etc/zabbix/zabbix-agent2.d/**/.conf

does not work.

Any further ideas?

Comment: It is broken. See https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-22548?jql=text%20~%20%22postgres%22
They've broke it several versions ago in LTS branch and not fixing it for months. Power of opensource.